# AR1 and Law Of Iterated Expectations : No serial correlation

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, linear-model

In the AR(1) model $y_{t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}y_{t-1}+u_{t}$, assuming $E(u_{t-1}|y_{t-1},y_{t-2}...)=0$, how does the law of iterated expectations ensure that the errors must be uncorrelated: $E(u_{t}u_{s}|x_{t},x_{s})=0$?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? In any event, the statement that errors are uncorrelated is an *assumption* of the AR(1) model, not a (genuine) derivable result.

Comment: No not homework - reading through Woolridge intro - page 385. It is stated that given AR(1) and the assumption that the error term has zero mean given all past values of y, the errors are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $s \neq t$. The law of iterated expectations tells us that

$$\begin{equation*} \mathbb{E}[u_su_t \mid y_{s-1}, y_{t-1}] =
\mathbb{E}_{u_s}\left[\mathbb{E}[u_su_t \mid u_s, y_{s-1}, y_{t-1}]\right] =
\mathbb{E}_{u_s}\left[u_s\mathbb{E}[u_t \mid u_s, y_{s-1}, y_{t-1}]\right]. \end{equation*} $$

Suppose that $s < t$, with the opposite case following by symmetry.

The AR(1) process has the property that, for $y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + u_t$, $\mathbb{E}[u_t \mid y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}, \dots] = \mathbb{E}[u_t \mid y_{t-1}] = 0$. In words, if I know what happened last period, then nothing else in the past can help me guess what happens today.

Rewriting our AR(1) equation reveals that $u_s = y_s - \beta_0 - \beta_1 y_{s-1}$; there is a one-to-one transformation betweent $u_s$ and $y_s$. As a result, conditioning on $u_s$ is equivalent to conditioning on $y_s$.

Using this relationship and our fact about the AR(1) process, we find that
$$\begin{equation*} \mathbb{E}[u_t \mid u_s, y_{s-1}, y_{t-1}] = 
\mathbb{E}[u_t \mid y_s, y_{s-1}, y_{t-1}] =
\mathbb{E}[u_t \mid y_{t-1}] = 0. \end{equation*} $$

Plugging this in to the LIE result above gives that
$$\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{u_s}\left[u_s\mathbb{E}[u_t \mid u_s, y_{s-1}, y_{t-1}]\right] =
\mathbb{E}_{u_s}\left[u_s \times 0\right] = 0. \end{equation*} $$

Comment: In the first part, the conditioning is on $y_{s-1},y_{t-1}$ correct? And when you condition on on $u_{s}$ that amounts to making $u_{s}$ a constant?

Comment: Yes to both points.