# Woolridge Intro Book: Question on Wording/Logic Conditioning

Tags: probability, econometrics

I am reading through Woolridge's Introductory book on Econometrics (I have no past exposure to it) and periodically get stuck. Here are two questions:

1) If we look at the expected value $E(YX|X)$ where Y and X are random variables, then is this saying since we condition on X, $E(YX|X) = XE(Y|X)$ as X is now a constant? Conditioning on a random variable makes it a constant generally?

2) On page 398, the author notes that with $s<t, (\textbf X_{t},\textbf X_{s},u_{s})$ is a subset of the conditioning set in (11.39 on page 397) : $E(u_{t}|\textbf X_{t}, u_{t-1},\textbf X_{t-1}, u_{t-2}...)=0$ this implies that $E(u_{t}|\textbf X_{t},\textbf X_{s}, u_{s})=0$.  Why is this? I would think since $(\textbf X_{t},\textbf X_{s},u_{s})$ is a subset of the conditioning set from 11.39 it would not imply the result since a subset doesn't condition on all the variables needed.

This question is related somewhat to another one [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47707/ar1-and-law-of-iterated-expectations-no-serial-correlation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can actually say something a little stronger:
   \begin{equation}
   E[Y\cdot h(X) + g(X) \mid X]=h(X) \cdot E[Y \mid X] +g(X),
   \end{equation}
   for any deterministic functions $h()$ and $g()$.
2. If I understand your question correctly, this is a consequence of the Law of Iterated Expectations. If I simplify the notation:
   \begin{equation}
   E[Y \mid X]= E[E[Y \mid X,Z] \mid X]=E[0 \mid X]=0,
   \end{equation}

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? Perhaps can you derive why $E[Y \mid X]= E[E[Y \mid X,Z] \mid X]$? Or better yet as Woolridge has: $E(u_{t}u_{s}|{\bf x_{t}},{\bf x_{s}})=E[E(u_{t}u_{s}|{\bf x_{t}},{\bf x_{s}},u_{s}){\bf x_{t}},{\bf x_{s}}]$

Comment: Should be why does $E(u_{t}u_{s}|{\bf x_{t}},{\bf x_{s}})=E[E(u_{t}u_{s}|{\bf x_{t}},{\bf x_{s}},u_{s})|{\bf x_{t}},{\bf x_{s}}]$

Comment: You can find a proof of that version of LIE here: http://www.sfu.ca/~cmuris/2012-Fall-435/ProblemSet2_answer.pdf.

Comment: The proof is for the discrete case, but the continuous version is pretty similar.